# Exception [EclipseLink-3002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.2.qualifier): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ConversionException

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, jpa-2.0, clob

I am trying to fetch a Table records, in Java Entity class, where one column is defined as CLOB. when I execute my select query I get following error:-

[EclipseLink-3002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.2.qualifier): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ConversionException error.

Below is the details of code..........

---

In database, I have CLOB column. I am executing a select query on Entity. Below is the detail.

In data base table MSG column is defined as CLOB.

My Entity class is below.

```
            @Entity
            @Table( name = "MyTable", schema="TEST" )
            @NamedQueries({ 
                @NamedQuery( name = "MyTable.findByChangeKey", query = "SELECT t FROM MyTable t WHERE t.changeKey = :changeKey)
                } )

            public class MyTable implements Serializable {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
                @Id
                @Basic( optional = false )
                @Column( name = "ID", nullable = false )
                private Integer msgId;
                @Basic( optional = false )
                @Column( name = "CHANGE_KEY", nullable = false, length = 15 )
                private String changeKey;


                @Column( name = "MSG")
                @Lob
                private byte[] msg;


                public Tsmtidsm() {
                }

                public byte[] getMsg() {
                    if(msg!=null)
                    {
                    return (byte[])msg.clone();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return msg;
                    }        
                }

                public void setMsg( byte[] msg ) {
                    if(msg!=null)
                    {
                    this.msg = (byte[])msg.clone();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.msg=null;
                    }        
                }

                public Tsmtidsm( Integer msgId ) {
                    this.msgId = msgId;
                }

                public Integer getMsgId() {
                    return msgId;
                }

                public void setMsgId( Integer msgId ) {
                    this.msgId = msgId;
                }

                public String getChangeKey() {
                    return changeKey;
                }

                public void setChangeKey( String changeKey ) {
                    this.changeKey = changeKey;
                }
            }
```

---

and below is the code line where I call the my select query

```
            Query searchQuery = em.createNamedQuery( "MyTable.findByChangeKey" );           
            searchQuery.setParameter("changeKey", serialNumber );

           List<MyTable> myTable=(List<MyTable>)searchQuery.getResultList();
```

---

I get following error while executing above code.

```
            Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-3002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.2.qualifier): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ConversionException
            Exception Description: The object [[B@2b2d02e5], of class [class java.lang.String], from mapping [org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DirectToFieldMapping[msg-->TEST.MyTable.MSG]] with descriptor [RelationalDescriptor(com.dao.data.MyTable--> [DatabaseTable(TEST.MyTable)])], could not be converted to [class [B].
                at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ConversionException.couldNotConvertToByteArray(ConversionException.java:115)
```

Please help, I am not sure what is wrong in above code, could anyone help me here? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

CLOB needs to be `char[]` not `byte[]` ..... `byte[]` is for BLOB